# How to shuffle the array index of same grade on each page refresh?

Tags: php

**e.g grade = 8, id = 724 but index can be  0 to 2 randomly, grade=6, id=899 index can be any between 3 to 6 on page refresh and for other grade index should be in same manner. I need every time when the page gets reload the index value of same grade should be reshuffle within it's own index value **

```
$arrval = Array ( 
Array ( 'id' => 19, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 20, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 21, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 22, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ), 
Array ( 'id' => 899, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ), 
Array ( 'id' => 898, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 897, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 896, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 895, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 894, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 724, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 3 )
);    
foreach ($arrval as $key => $row)
{       
    $grade[$key]  = $row['grade'];
}    
 array_multisort($grade, SORT_DESC, $arrval);  

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrval);exit;    

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 724
            [grade] => 8
            [county] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 894
            [grade] => 8
            [county] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 895
            [grade] => 8
            [county] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 896
            [grade] => 6
            [county] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 897
            [grade] => 6
            [county] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 898
            [grade] => 6
            [county] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 899
            [grade] => 6
            [county] => 10
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [grade] => 5
            [county] => 219
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [grade] => 5
            [county] => 219
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [grade] => 5
            [county] => 219
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [grade] => 5
            [county] => 219
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would shuffle the results before ordering them by grade.

```
<?php

// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['grade'] == $b['grade']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['grade'] < $b['grade']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$arrval = Array ( 
Array ( 'id' => 19, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 20, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 21, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ),
Array ( 'id' => 22, 'grade' => 5, 'county' => 219 ), 
Array ( 'id' => 899, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ), 
Array ( 'id' => 898, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 897, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 896, 'grade' => 6, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 895, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 894, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 10 ),
Array ( 'id' => 724, 'grade' => 8, 'county' => 3 )
); 

shuffle($arrval);

usort($arrval, "cmp");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrval);
exit;
```